# Using An Array In Else-If Statement

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

Just need a little help here for a personal-learning project. I've searched numerous similar posts with no luck.

The goal is to shorten my code by using an array within the following else-if statement (rather than having 40+ else-if's re-iterating the same thing).

The following code is working if I spell out each else-if statement, I'm simply looking to improve it.

```
<?php
$affiliate1 = array('productA', 'productB', 'productC', 'productD', 'ProductE', 'productF');
?>

<?php
$affiliate2 = array('productG', 'productH', 'productI', 'productJ', 'ProductK', 'productL');
?>

<?php $returnaddress = $_POST['product_name']; ?>
<?php if ($returnaddress == "$affiliate1") $returnaddress = 'Address1';
 elseif ($returnaddress == "$affiliate2") $returnaddress = 'Address2';
?>

<?php echo $returnaddress;?>
```

Any help/explanation is greatly appreciated! I've searched for a few hours but haven't been able to find examples specific enough to my case.

Comment: Are you looking for [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) -> `if (in_array($returnaddress, $affiliate1)) $returnaddress = 'Address1'; elseif (in_array($returnaddress, $affiliate2)) $returnaddress = 'Address2';`?

Comment: Why is $affiliate1 between " in your code?

Comment: Why not use a [switch](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php)?

Comment: Not sure why you have $affiliate1 and $affiliate2 in quotes. Try to search for find match in array using php.

Comment: I'm only a month into learning php - thus all the syntax mistakes.  I'm doing research into in_array now!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Sean for pointing this out! I needed to use in_array, which I didn't know existed!

Here's the working code he provided

```
<?php
$affiliate1 = array('productA', 'productB', 'productC', 'productD', 'ProductE', 'productF');
?>

<?php
$affiliate2 = array('productG', 'productH', 'productI', 'productJ', 'ProductK', 'productL');
?>


if (in_array($returnaddress, $affiliate1)) $returnaddress = 'Address1'; 
elseif (in_array($returnaddress, $affiliate2)) $returnaddress = 'Address2';
```

Comment: Just a tip -- if you're writing a script that is just php, you don't need to open and close the `<?php` `?>` declarations every line; just start the script with `<?php`. You only need to use that syntax if you're interspersing your php in an HTML file. It would get pretty annoying having to write `<?php` before every line of code! `:)`

Comment: Thanks! Knowing that, you would probably cringe at the complete code. I'll start looking into that.

Comment: It should save you a bit of typing, anyway! :D